# Is there a way to restrict my program installation to a certain web-source on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, security, malware, installer

I have a program HelloWorld, signed by me and distributed from my company site. But someone has downloaded it from my site, wrapped into program SuperDuperHelloWorld and also added some malware into installer. I don't want my program to install properly, if it's not downloaded from my site directly. Is there a way to put such restrictions? - Maybe not always, but in some percent of cases, say 95%.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering the same thing for a long time, but I haven't been able to elaborate more on this, because I don't have all the knowledge required, but **this is just an idea**:

1. Generate random key pairs. Generate a *hash* of the current version of your binary. Store them on a local database.
2. Bundle one *public* key with the download, e.g. send it via e-mail to the client.
3. The client opens the app and they're greeted by a verification window. The verification process asks for the *public* key and generates a *hash* of the binary.
4. The client sends the *public* key and the binary's *hash* to your servers and you check it against the *secret* key and the *hash* for that binary version on the database.
5. The response is cyphered using the *public* key via a *secret* algorithm, so any potential scammer couldn't intercept the connection and make your app think that it has been properly verified.
6. You can store the *public* key and the cyphered response on a *secret* file so you don't have to repeat the *validation* process everytime. You just decrypt the response using the *secret* algorithm and the *public* key to know if it was properly validated.

The downsides of this approach:

1. The client must have an internet connection, at least once.
2. The client's program couldn't be *verified* twice (e.g. on different computers), even if it's a legitimate client.
3. Although the storage of the file and response is cyphered, that won't prevent any attacker to know its location and bundle the *validation pair* with any *stolen* binary to bypass your security.
4. The hashing process of the binary may take a while if the binary is relatively big.

This won't prevent any *scammer* to download your app and re-distribute it, but at least they won't be able to inject any `malware` into it, because of the *hash*-check… will they? actually they could; the validation process could be cracked if the scammer somehow manages to modify your binary and adds the proper instructions to bypass the security of the validation process. Something like…

Changing this

```
if (validate(response) == true) {
    /* The app is validated */
}
```

For this:

```
if (!validate(response) == true || true) {
    /* 
    * The app would be validated no matter
    * if it was properly validated or not
    */
}
```

So your last resource would be to make the instructions of the validation process obscure enough to not be easily guessed and modified and *hope* that your *scammer* isn't intelligent enough to find and modify them.